# Large difference in .csv file size

Tags: r, csv

I have two .csv files:

- Table A with 32075892 rows which takes 2023365kb
- Table B with 21383928 rows which only takes 1051836kb

Both tables have the same number of columns with about the same content (An Id, An integer, A short string (always the same size), A numeric, Another String). The only difference is that for table A the String values of the last columns are slightly longer: 26.83 chars on average compared to 9.

I read and wrote both .csv files with fread and fwrite from the data.table package in R.

Table A has 50% more rows than B, but takes twice the space in file size. What is the reason for the large difference in file size?

Comment: Hi Ruben,
Have you checked encoding of files?

Comment: No, but I wrote both files using the same R function, so I would guess both files are encoded the same way.

Comment: UTF-8 uses 2 bytes instead of 1 in ASCII coding, If you have some non-ASCII symbols, it may be the cause. You can open these files with something like Notepad and see encoding.

Comment: File is too large to be opened in Notepad or Notepad++. I am looking for a way too check the encoding.

Comment: Right, files are too big. May be you can check with smaller files (some subset of data)?

Comment: Table A: ANSI encoding. Table B: also ANSI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193013/discussion-between-yuriy-barvinchenko-and-ruben).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the average record length for the 2 files:

```
    int recordLengthFile1= (2023365 * 1024) / 32075892; 
    int recordLengthFile2= (1051836 * 1024) / 21383928 ;
```

This gives record lengths of **64** and **50** a difference of 14 which is close to  the difference between the last fields in the file 26.83 - 9 = 17.83

Comment: Thank you, makes me think that choosing shorter names might be very advantageous in some cases.